# Ruby TZInfo and Rails ActiveSupport::Timezone UTC_offset differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I want to find the total UTC offset from a Timezone Object. Below are two examples using `TZInfo::Timezone` and `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`. Ultimately, I want to use the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` implementation, but can't get it to give me the right answer.

```
#TZInfo implementation
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
tz.current_period.utc_total_offset / 60 / 60
=> -4 (CORRECT)

# Rails implementation
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
tz.utc_offset / 60 / 60
=> -5 (WRONG)
```

Why does `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` appear to fail to factor in dst? How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the [ActiveSupport documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-utc_offset). Basically, it is running `tzinfo.current_period.utc_offset` instead of `tzinfo.current_period.utc_total_offset`

```
def utc_offset
  if @utc_offset
    @utc_offset
  else
    tzinfo.current_period.utc_offset if tzinfo && tzinfo.current_period
  end
end
```

So to fully answer my question: I need the following code...

```
tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
tz.tzinfo.current_period.utc_total_offset / 60 / 60
```